# How to detect mailto links with Hpricot/Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, css-selectors, nokogiri, hpricot

I want to match links like `<a href="mailto:my@email.com">foo</a>`, but this <strike>doesn't work</strike> only works in Nokogiri:

```
doc/'a[href ^="mailto:"]'
```

<strike>What's the right way of doing that?</strike> How do I do that with Hpricot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on Hpricot:

```
doc/'a[@href ^="mailto:"]'
```

Couldn't figure out a way to do the xpath search though. Apparently, Hpricot doesn't support `starts-with`: http://wiki.github.com/hpricot/hpricot/supported-xpath-expressions

Answer (score 3):

```
doc/"//a[starts-with(@href,'mailto')]"
```

Comment: I tried that, also didn't work. Then I switched to Nokogiri and both examples worked. I thought they had similar APIs. Doesn't Hpricot also support css-selector/xpath searches? Do you know how to do the same in Hpricot?